# how to make manual indexing in ecomdev_phpunit catalogsearch tests with bulk products?

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

I am trying to test custom layered navigation filter (catalogsearch controller) functions and creating bulk products like this in my test:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $productNumber; $i++) {
            // random data generation
            $productInstance->setData($conditionsData);
            $productInstance->setName($randomTitle)
                ->setTypeId('virtual')
                ->setDescription($randomDesc)
                ->setSku($randomDesc)
                ->setAttributeSetId(4)
                ->setStatus(96)
                ->setVisibity(4)
                ->setPrice(rand(777,999))
                ->save();

            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts(array(1), array($productInstance->getId()));
            Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext')->rebuildIndex(1, $productInstance->getId());
        }
```

I noticted when dispatching a `catalogsearch/result/index` request it is making query to `catalog_category_product_index` and `catalog_product_index_price` but this is a test case and these tables are empty, so i am trying to build index like following:

```
      $indexCodes = array('catalog_product_attribute',
        'catalog_product_price',
        'catalog_url',
        'catalog_product_flat',
        'catalog_category_flat',
        'catalog_category_product',
        'cataloginventory_stock',
        'filter_attribute',
        'tag_summary');


    foreach ($indexCodes as $indexCodeSingle) {
                $index = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($indexCodeSingle);
                $index->reindexEverything();
            }
```

But after running indexing code my `catalog_category_product_index` and `catalog_product_index_price` are empty, why ?
Maybe I forgot to add some attributes to to products while creating them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I was required to have `catalog_product_price` index built, so far it depends on `cataloginventory_stock` which required stock parameters in product creation:

```
productInstance->setName($randomTitle)
                    ->setDescription($randomDesc)
                    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                    ->setStoreId(1)
                    ->setTypeId('virtual')
                    ->setOriginalLanguage(array_rand($langs))
                    ->setSku($randomDesc)
                    ->setStockData(array(
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // 'Use config settings' checkbox
                            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                            'qty' => 1
                        )
                    )
                    ->setAttributeSetId(4)
                    ->setStatus(1)
                    ->setVisibity(4)
                    ->setPrice(rand(777, 999))
                    ->save();
```

Seems like virtual product stock also required to be configured.